# xfce4-power-manager suspend not available for lid close

Tags: power-management, xfce

Running a clean install of ubuntustudio 14.04 the suspend and resume works when using the power button or selecting it from the user menu but is not available in the xfce4-power-manager-settings. Only "Lock Screen" or "Nothing" is available for lid close action.

http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq 
Suggests that it is likely permissions issue since suspend/resume clearly works.

My single user on a single user system has the following group memberships: username adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Any suggestions? I'd rather not fry my new hdd because I forgot to suspend and just close the lid.

Updates:

- Changing "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" settings have no effect.
- This appears to be a bug in upower https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1005234
- I've confirmed this is not an issue with my hardware on the standard ubuntu desktop (using a live drive)
- I've confirmed this is not an issue with xubuntu!?! (I had to enable suspend in the xfce4-power-manager-settings but it was an option)
- Changing kernel to linux-general has no affect.
- xfce4-power-manager --dump & sudo xfce4-power-mangager --dump

```
---------------------------------------------------
       Xfce power manager version 1.2.0
With policykit support
With network manager support
With DPMS support
---------------------------------------------------
Can suspend: False
Can hibernate: False
Can spin down hard disks: True
Authorized to suspend: True
Authorized to hibernate: True
Authorized to shutdown: True
Authorized to spin down hard disks: False
Has battery: True
Has brightness panel: True
Has power button: True
Has hibernate button: True
Has sleep button: True
Has LID: True
```

Comment: Does a change in the "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" have any affect? Try to uncomment "#HandleLidSwitch=suspend" to "HandleLidSwitch=suspend" (without quotes). More info: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html

Comment: Yes I have tried that setting in "/etc/systemd/logind.conf", it doesn't seem to have any affect on either the suspend behavior or the availability of suspend in the xfce4-power-manager-settings program.

Comment: Did you restart the systemd daemon after the changes `sudo restart systemd-logind` ?

Comment: I restarted the computer. That restarts the systemd daemon right?

Comment: Yes. What did you see if you open the power-manager as root: `sudo xfce4-power-manager-settings` ?

Comment: I had to start a root owned instance of xfce4-power-manager. After that I get the same options for root as my local user.

Comment: Is there a file `/etc/acpi/handler.sh` look at this https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=8229.msg72591#msg72591 or something similar ?

Comment: no /etc/acpi/handler.sh does not exist, the only file that contains any mention of suspend is /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh

Comment: no file contains a mention of a [l,L][i,I][d,D]

Comment: What did you change in the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`?

Comment: I uncommented the HandleLidSwitch=suspend line. I've also uncommented the LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes and tried every one of those 4 possibilities, though I believe that is the default behavior for the LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited.

Comment: @NateIverson, Do you have `pm-utils` installed? see https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7250

Comment: Sneetsher, I previously had tried pm-utils but wasn't sure if I had rebooted it. I double checked with the xubuntu iso and xubuntu has pm-utils installed by default. Trying again with a reboot solves the problem. Submit as an answer and I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @Sneetsher Sorry I clicked the bounty but forgot to click the answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install `pm-utils`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pm-utils
   ```
2. Reboot

Reference: [[Solved] Issues with xfce4-power-manager-1.2.0](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7250)

Discussion resume that: `upower` is relying on `pm-utils` to check for suspend/hibernate capability.

The broken link in the reference page should point to related bug report:
[Debian bug#639754 [upower] upower doesn't verify correctly the "suspend" and "hibernate" capabilities correctly](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639754)

Not sure about this as `upower` package has `Depends: pm-utils | systemd | systemd-services`. I thought they should be alternatives. So may be there is other solution using `systemd-services` which is installed by default.

Comment: This didn't work for me (I have the same xfce4-power-manager as the OP) but I could restore the suspend when lid closed behaviour using the xfconf commands on this page http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq

Comment: @Joce nice, i was pretty sure there is other solution using systemd. I can't test it. However it should have separate answer, could you write one.

Answer (score 4):

The same symptoms and output of `xfce4-power-manager` can be observed with `pm-utils` installed. In that case, it is possible at least to restore the suspend when lid is closed using the information on [Xfce4 FAQ page](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq), section "How can I make logind handle button events":

> To have logind handle the lid open/close event:  `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch -n -t bool -s true`
>
> To have logind handle the power key:  `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-power-key -n -t bool -s true`
>
> To have logind handle the suspend key:  `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-suspend-key -n -t bool -s true`
>
> To have logind handle the hibernate key:  `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-hibernate-key -n -t bool -s true`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the power management GUI xfce provides:
https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/preferences